# How to fix this error "Failed to create provisioning profile."

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

[image]

I git clone from my friend project and show me this error.
I already add my apple account in xcode.
And I fix this issue when I change my bundle ID.
I have a question. When I submit the app to the app store,the bundle ID doesn't match previous version.
Is it successful to submit or failed to submit? 
If it is failed, how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your new bundle ID, then it will not create any problem. Just a new app will be published. i.e. Previous app downloads, reviews and other information will not be added with this app. In short, if this is for the first time you are uploading it, then no problem will occur.

Comment: This app is published. App store can download it.

Comment: I just help him to fix bug. And I want to bulid in my iphone. I don't know how to fix this error.

Comment: Use your friend's account, use same bundle id as your friends, fix the issue  and then publish. Or just give back the fixed codes to your friend's computer and publish from there.

Comment: Thanks your advice.